# Speed up implementation of "log transform" on 2D image

Tags: c++, performance

I'm working on an implementation of the "log transform" operator on an image for C++, and we currently have it formulated as follows (python code). Note we use log10 instead of the natural log.

```py
def log_transform(mat: np.ndarray, dB: int = 40):
    mat= 255 * (20/dB * np.log10(mat/ mat.max()) + 1)
    mat[mat< 1] = 0
    return mat
```

Now in OpenCV and C++, I have the following implementation and I'm not happy with its performance.  What's confusing to me is that I have another function that does a Hilbert transform on the same image (fft, ifft, copying into buffers etc.) and it has the same average run time as this `log_transform` function, which should be `O(n)` and transforms in-place.

```cpp
    void log_transform(cv::Mat& mat, double db) {
        assert(mat.isContinuous());
        double maxval;
        cv::minMaxIdx(mat, (double*)0, &maxval);

        // OpenCV only implements natural log, and we need log10
        double* const ptr = (double*)mat.data;
        const double fct = 20 / db;

        #pragma omp parallel for private(i, v)
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows * mat.cols; i++) {
            double& v = *(ptr + i);
            v = 255. * (fct * std::log10(v / maxval) + 1.);
            v = v < 1. ? 0. : v;
        }
    }
```

Interestingly, using `#pragma omp parallel for` doesn't improve the average runtime (maybe 10% slow down). I set `omp_set_num_threads` to the number of physical cores I have, not number of virtual cores with hyperthreading. (Setting it to the number of virtual cores actually degrades performance even more, probably due to the sync overhead). I've also tried to tune `schedule(static, CHUNK_SIZE)` with no success.

From profilers (I used both Visual Studio performance profiler and Intel VTune), most of the CPU time is spent in `std::log10`. I'm not sure what else to look for in the profiler output to help me improve this function.

On an image of input size (1000, 6400) the runtimes:

- Python: `146 ms ± 4.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`
- C++: `108 ms ± 8.72 (mean ± std. dev. of 15 runs)`

Compiler: Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.11.23, which I believe implements OpenMP 2.x). MSVC and Clang give similar results.

CPU: Intel i5 Haswell

My questions:

1. How can I improve the performance of this `log_transform` function? I thought about SIMD but I'm not sure how to do `log10`.
2. Why doesn't OpenMP improve the performance of the loop?

### Edit: after enabling the `/openmp` compiler flag

As suggested by `Doc Brown`, I also set the loop range `nrows` and `ncols` outside the loop definition, in case the compiler doesn't know they're constant.

Raw OpenMP version:

```cpp
        void log_transform(cv::Mat& mat, double db) {
            assert(mat.isContinuous());
            double maxval;
            cv::minMaxIdx(mat, (double*)0, &maxval);

            const double fct = 20. / db;

            const int nrows = mat.rows;
            const int ncols = mat.cols;
    #pragma omp parallel for
            for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
                auto row = (double*)mat.ptr(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
                    double& v = row[j];
                    v = 255. * (fct * std::log10(v / maxval) + 1.);
                    v = v < 1.0 ? 0 : v;
                }
            }

        }
```

OpenCV `parallel_for_` version

```cpp
    void log_transform(cv::Mat& mat, double db) {
            assert(mat.isContinuous());
            double maxval;
            cv::minMaxIdx(mat, (double*)0, &maxval);

            const double fct = 20. / db;

            const int nrows = mat.rows;
            const int ncols = mat.cols;

            // OpenCV only implements natural log, and we need log10
            auto par_log_transform = [&mat, maxval, fct, ncols](const cv::Range& range) {
                for (int i = range.start; i < range.end; ++i) {
                    auto row = (double*)mat.ptr(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
                        double& v = row[j];
                        v = 255. * (fct * std::log10(v / maxval) + 1.);
                        v = v < 1.0 ? 0 : v;
                    }
                }
            };
            cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, nrows), par_log_transform);
        }
```

Use natural log as suggested by user `Useless`:

```
        void log_transform(cv::Mat& mat, double db) {
            assert(mat.isContinuous());
            double maxval;
            cv::minMaxIdx(mat, (double*)0, &maxval);

            cv::log(mat / maxval, mat);
            mat = 255. * (20. / db / cv::log(10) * mat + 1.);
        }
```

Runtime:

- raw OpenMP: `35.8 ± 4.7 ms (15 runs)`
- OpenCV `parallel_for_`: `29.1 ± 5.4 ms (15 runs)`
- Natural log version: `89.0 ± 12.8 ms (15 runs)`

I'm not sure which backend OpenCV's `parallel_for_` uses (it apparently supports a lot of backends, such as OpenMP, Intel TBB...) but it seems that it optimizes better than my custom OpenMP loop.

The current winner is OpenCV's `parallel_for_`.

Comment: I am trolling... I didn't enabled `/openmp` in the compiler flag, and apparently the `omp.h` header just stubs it out and the compiler simply ignores all the `omp` directives...

Comment: Wouldn't this squarely fall under the "assistance for using coding tools" off-topic category?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner: I think it is an edge case. I think we should vote for closing this question inj case we expect the OP to find more experts on this topic on Stackoverflow, or we can keep it in case we think our experts here might be able to answer the question,

Comment: @kwsp: you are using a `double` matrix, but you mentioned this is image data. In what range are the values in this matrix? And are these just grey scale values? I ask because with some range constraints it might be possible to replace `std::log10` by a lookup table.

Comment: ... also, just to be sure: assign `mat.rows * mat.cols` to a variable *before* the loop, the compiler might not be able to figure out this stays constant during the loop. I don't know how the `#pragma parallel for` exactly works, but I can imagine it requires a constant upper loop limit.

Comment: Going further on @DocBrown's comment: what is the precision-requirement?  Reducing the required precision would allow you to use smaller data types and lookup tables.

Comment: You know `log10(x) = log2(x) / log2(10)`, right? You can just pre-compute `log2(10)` and use fast `log2` operations.

Comment: @kwsp: ... note, reading your first comment, it is unclear if the observations you described in the question are still valid, or if adding the compiler flag changed those. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Useless shouldn't it be natural log ln since log2(x)=ln(x)/ln(2)? :) (keeping in mind it is floating point log2, not integer truncated log2 that can be done bitwise)

Comment: @user253751: both formulas are correct. And I would expect std::log10 to be implemented in the standard library exactly that way, so it is unlikely this will bring any speed-up (but don't take my word, try it out).

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, `/openmp` improved a lot, I will update the question.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Where would this question be more appropriate for?

Comment: @DocBrown the input data is RF signal, and this `log_transform` function is a part of the pipeline that converts it into an image.

Comment: @DocBrown raw data comes from a 12-bit DAQ. I'm not actually sure what's the range here, since its after a ton of pre processing already (filtering, Hilbert transform etc.) This step is the log compression that converts whatever data we get into a [0-255] image.

Comment: Well, if you are happy with the speed now, I would just stay with the solution you have. You may replace `std::log10(v / maxval) ` by  `std::log10(v) - std::log10(maxval) ` and keep the second term in another helper variable, But I am unsure if that will bring you any measurable performance difference.

Comment: @DocBrown that brought a small improvement! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Another thing I would try is not to use a reference variable. Try out `double v = row[j];`, then the calculation, and finally row[j] = v; Not sure what will happen, but there might be a chance the compiler will produce some code which keeps the intermediate values longer in a CPU register, and not store them back too early to memory.